# Trouble with facet counts

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm attempting to use ElasticSearch for analytics -- specifically to track "top content" for hand-rolled Rails CMS. The requirement is quite a bit more complicated than keeping a counter for each piece of content. I won't get into the depth of problem right now, as I can't seem to get even the basics working.

My problem is this: I'm using facets and the counts aren't what I expect them to be. For example:

Query:

```
{"facets":{"el_ids":{"terms":{"field":"el_id","size":1,"all_terms":false,"order":"count"}}}}
```

Result:

```
{"el_ids":{"_type":"terms","missing":0,"total":16672,"other":16657,"terms":[{"term":"quis","count":15}]}}
```

Ok, great, the piece of content with id "quis" had 15 hits and since the `order` is `count`, it should be my top piece of content. Now lets get the top 5 pieces of content.

Query:

```
{"facets":{"el_ids":{"terms":{"field":"el_id","size":5,"all_terms":false,"order":"count"}}}}
```

Result (just the facet):

```
[
  {"term":"qgz9","count":26},
  {"term":"quis","count":15},
  {"term":"hnqn","count":15},
  {"term":"higp","count":15},
  {"term":"csns","count":15}
]
```

Huh? So the piece of content w/ id "qgz9" had more hits with 26? Why wasn't it the top result in the first query?

Ok, lets get the top 100 now.

Query:

```
{"facets":{"el_ids":{"terms":{"field":"el_id","size":100,"all_terms":false,"order":"count"}}}}
```

Results (just the facet):

```
[
  {"term":"qgz9","count":43},
  {"term":"difc","count":37},
  {"term":"zryp","count":31},
  {"term":"u65r","count":31},
  {"term":"sxsi","count":31},
  ...
]
```

So now "qgz9" has 43 hits instead of 26? How can that be? I can assure you there's nothing happening in the background modifying the index. If I repeat these queries, I get the same results.

As I repeat this process of increasing the result size, counts continue to change and new content ids emerge at the top. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong or where my understanding of how this works is flawed?

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that this is a [known issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1305):

> ...the way top N facets work now is by getting the top N from each shard, and merging the results. This can give inaccurate results.

By default, my index was being created with 5 shards. By changing this so the index only has a single shard, the counts behave inline with my expectations. Another workaround would be to always set `size` to a value greater than the number of expected facets and peel off the top N  results.

Comment: This is still not the good way to achieve that. Sharding is a very important feature of Elasticsearch. You might loose a lot performance-wise if you consider only 1 shard.